# How to get the present dimension of a JFrame during run time

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

I want to get the present size of my Jframe whenever i click on the button1. This is the code which i have written in my button1clickevent initially when i click on the button i do get a width and height but when i change the size of my Jframe and then again i click on button1 i get the same width and height as i got earlier.The values are not changing anytime.

```
  AppDisplay ap=new AppDisplay(); //class which has got the JFrame
    int f12;
  f12=ap.getContentPane().getSize().width;
  System.out.println(f12+"\n");
  f12=ap.getContentPane().getSize().height;
  System.out.println(f12);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your referencing the wrong `Object`. What's `AppDisplay` & why do you need a new instance?

Also, what's wrong with `Frame.getSize();` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the size of the Content Pane which is inside the JFrame.  Use the JFrame's `getSize()` method to get the size of the frame.

```
 final Dimension size = ap.getSize();
 System.out.println(size);
```

Also, MadProgrammer makes a good point that the code you show creates a new instance of `AppDisplay`.  You can create as many instances as you want, even without showing them.  You will always want to carefully consider the lifecycle of the objects and the scope of the variable names that reference them so that you can refer to the intended object every time.

Comment: This result is valid after `pack()` on the frame's `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

one idea i found that. 
Place a jButton ("jbutton1") one the jFrame.
and write the code inaction performed of the buton.

System.out.println(this.getSize());

then run the frame.
adjust the frame to required size.
then click the button..
we will get the updated size..
then we can set it as the actual size of the frame from properties of jframe...